# How to make tinyMCE content for ASP.Net MVC as XHTML strict?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce, xhtml-1.0-strict

How to make tinyMCE editor content of ASP.Net MVC page to XHTML strict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google search turns up this detailed article:

http://www.gethifi.com/blog/how-to-produce-xhtml-10-strict-markup-with-tinymce

Did you try that already?

Comment: I have already read this article. In some cases the html of the tinyMCE editor is not converted well to xhtml. Thanks for your reply